# Rewrite rules for response headers in IIS 7 (replacing the cookie path)

Tags: iis, cookies, url-rewriting, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I have to port my web application from apache to IIS 7 and got into trouble with the proper configuration.

In the apache configuration, I configured some mod rewrite stuff (in order to communicate with an apache active mq) like this:

```
#Reverse-Proxy to ActiveMQ AJAX-Interface
ProxyPass        /foo/bar/amq http://localhost:8161/foo/amq/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/bar/amq http://localhost:8161/foo/amq/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /foo /
```

I've tried to configure the IIS 7 by using [ApplicationRequestRouting](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting). 
The rewrite rule in the request for replacing the /foo/bar to the localhost adress does  already work, but I've some problems to define a rule for setting up the correct cookie path in the response.

I've already found an article about manipulating responses [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/658/using-outbound-rules-to-add-web-analytics-tracking-code/).
For me, it looks like with II7 I can only manipulate the HTTP body of the response.

How can I manipulate the response header in a way to edit the cookie path?

The cookie path in the response header looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1lu7hn253csbh11jax27k2i072;Path=/foo
```

The Path should be edited to "Path=/".

Thank for your time and your help 
Rolf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <remove name="Update Cookie Path" />
                <rule name="Update Cookie Path">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="^(.*; path=/)foo$" />
                    <conditions />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Check the more detailed [reference](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/665/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Setting_Response_Headers).

Comment: Thx a lot!!! It worked almost without Modification, you just saved my week ;) But REPONSE_SET_COOKIE is actually RESPONSE_Set_Cookie. Regards - Rolf