# Apache's ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse equivalent in IIS

Tags: apache, iis, mod-proxy, proxypass

Is there Apache's mod_proxy equivalent in IIS?

I have following configuration in my Apache's httpd.conf (mod_proxy enabled):

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=hej.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/;" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy balancer://openfire>
    BalancerMember http://server2:7070/http-bind/ route=1
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /project1/http-bind balancer://openfire nofailover=Off
ProxyPassReverse /project1/http-bind balancer://openfire
```

I need to do similar config for IIS. I tried ARR (Application Request Routing) but could not get it working.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, quickets option would be to Google for "IIS Reverse Proxy", and you'll find the likes of:

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing). For examples, there are many on StackOverflow already, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353861/rewrite-rules-for-response-headers-in-iis-7-replacing-the-cookie-path).